# SVG/D3 - JSON reload every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I program a D3/json/ajax query which invites new data every 10
seconds.

Here is my first approach for a solution, I think it is not good:

```
setInterval(function() {
  d3.json("http://1.....", function(json) {
  ....
  })

}, 1000);
```

As it is right or is there a better approach?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For timed execution of a method setInterval is your best option setTimeout could be used but setInterval for this purpose would be better. I would however ensure that your first ajax call has completed before triggering the function again.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example or a link to a sample?

Comment: @user800906 If the answer is helpful, accept it as the correct answer or upvote it